# Bootstrap 4 dropdown ul list not correct and fixed position

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, popper.js

Problem is bootstrap dropdown select list appear away from button. The position is not correct and not fixed with button. See the image down to understand issue. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="button-group dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Velg lokaler 
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu px-2" data-bind="foreach: bookable">
                <li>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-bind="text: name"/>
                        <label class="form-check-label" data-bind="text: name">

                        </label>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: The button should have position relative and the options wrapped in an element with position absolute.

Comment: Can you post all of the relevant code, or a minimal example that repros the issue?